# how to change ng-bind value of ng-repeat for single element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am just beginner in angular and developing shopping cart, now have problem to add 'Added!' value when I click on "add to cart" button.
Here is my code

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products"> <a ng-click="additem(item,$index)">add to cart</a><span>{{cartadded}}</div>
```

js

```
$scope.additem = function (product,index){$scope.productsList.push(product); var item=$scope.product[index]; item.cartadded="Added!"; }
```

Comment: It should be `{{item.cartadded}}` instead of just `{{cartadded}}` also, in the `additem` function you can do `product.cartadded="Added!"` there is no need to retrieve the item from the array using its index.

Comment: in both of case you told are not working ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track that status of each item individually. I've also cleaned up your code a bit:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in products">
  <a ng-click="additem($index)" ng-hide="item.cartadded">add to cart</a>
  <span ng-show="item.cartadded>Added!</span>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.additem = function(index) {
  var item = $scope.products[index];
  $scope.productsList.push(item);
  item.cartadded = true;
}
```

Comment: always this error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: WIthout seeing all of your code, that's not helpful. It sounds like you may be using the wrong variable name? Is $scope.product an array of all of your products?

Comment: @AJFunk That is probably because in this example `$scope.product[index];` is used instead of `$scope.products[index];`

Comment: ok sir thanks for help but can you give me working plunker for this patch of code? because it is still not working after adding "s"

Comment: sorry sir its working fine as my wish thank you alot . can you give me any contact for help in future?? please?

Comment: now how can i  make `item.cartadded=false;` on specific call ??

Answer (score 0):

so finally here is a solution for above the question for the help of other persons related this question

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in products">
    <a ng-click="additem1($index)" >add to cart</a>
    <span ng-show="item.cartadded">Added!</span>
</div>
```

js

```
  $scope.additem1 = function (index ){
    var item = $scope.products[index];
    $scope.productsList.push(item);
    item.cartadded = true;
};
```

some improved above answer and thanks for **AJ Funk**